# Google cloud compute engine unable to access external ip spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud compute engine where the external ip is 35.*.*.*. I put my Spring boot jar in the folder and ran java -jar app.jar. The jar is starting.

However, when i use postman to call the endpoint of the spring, i do not get a response. 
eg http://35.*.*.*/getallusers

Must I add some configurations for this to work?

Comment: Please update your question with more details: **1**. GCP firewall configuration **2**. Springboot configuration. Have you checked open open ports with `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM`?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely haven’t configured the firewall rules correctly.